# Permitir buscas ignorando acentuação

Tags: bug, novo-recurso, status-pronto, acentuação, busca

Reparei que o campo de busca do site, bem como o campo de busca rápida no diálogo de fechar como duplicata, não trazem resultados se a busca for feita sem acentos (por exemplo, `funcao` em vez de `função`).

Seria possível uma busca *accent-insensitive*, que ignorasse os acentos?

Idealmente, isso deveria valer também para todos os campos com *autocompletar* do site (tags, usuários, menções em comentários, etc.).

Comment: Pior é que como esse insensitive é o normal em quase qualquer search em português, muitas vezes deixamos de achar informações que estão no site achando que elas não existem mesmo. Editei as tags acrescentando [tag:bug], pois para nós não é mero novo recurso (entendo que seja novo recurso pra SE, dado o SOpt ser uma nova experiência)

Comment: Eu concordo que seria uma boa adição ao site, mas alguém pode me ajudar a explicar por que nós queremos ter a habilidade de procurar palavras escritas da forma errada?

Comment: Mudei para `status-aceito`, mas pode demorar um até termos uma idéia do trabalho (ou se sequer será feito). Então encarem como "estamos cientes"

Comment: Obrigado @Gabe. Respondendo sua pergunta acima: ao pesquisar *com* acentos, queremos poder encontrar palavras que foram postadas com ou sem acentos; e vice-versa.

Comment: @Gabe Pesquisa sem distinção por diacríticos é comum dada sua conveniência: é mais rápido digitar sem acentos, principalmente em dispositivos móveis. OS X, iOS e Windows usam esse tipo de pesquisa em suas funções de busca, bem como o Google e SGBDs como Oracle.